# Exactly which JavaScript version does Node.js understand by default?

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I use Node.js without a transpiler, i.e. something as simple as

```
node hello.js
```

what language is `hello.js`? I thought that, since Node.js is based on V8, it would be V8's language (presumably something close to a recent version of ECMAScript).

But Node also supports the `require()` function, which isn't in ECMAScript (or in V8).

Perhaps Node's language is V8 plus a subset of CommonJS? What subset?

Comment: Node.js only knows about JavaScript. CommonJS is not a language.

Comment: it's using something close to ES5, with some extensions as you've mentioned like `require`, the ecmascript's implementation is called javascript

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar Node has supported ES6+ for a *long* time now. It didn't completely fullysupport it (ES modules) until about two years ago but it's not really been "close" to ES5 for quite a while.

Comment: @VLAZ I thought it was clear from the question that I know that Node.js knows JavaScript, and that the question is which JavaScript. I changed the title to make it clearer.

Comment: https://node.green

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with every JavaScript engine out there,  Node.js supports:

- A collection of features from various versions of JS (since they get implemented feature-by-feature (as opposed to a single big release where ever change in a new version of ECMAScript is released at once). https://node.green/ maintains a list of features in various versions of ECMAScript and the support for them in different engines.
- A bunch of extensions in the form of APIs that aren't defined by the ECMAScript specification (e.g. for filesystem access and CommonJS module support)

Comment: So Node's language is roughly ECMAScript plus the (non-standard) features listed at https://nodejs.org/api/?

Comment: @AntonisChristofides - Every JS engine is roughly ECMAScript plus some non-standard features. (The APIs aren't part of the language though)

Comment: @AntonisChristofides non-standard *as per the ES specs*. A lot of those features are standard for Node.js. There are also some things for which there is no standard, e.g., `console.log` which shows you *something* but that output is not standardised.